# Maximize triple product with respect to orthogonality contraint

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have the following problem:
Suppose I have a plane $p$ defined by point $\vec{q}_1$ and normal vector $\vec{n}$.
Also I have a line $g_2$, defined by point $\vec{q}_2$ and direction $\vec{l}_2$ which does not lie on plane $p$.

I want to find a line $g_1$ with direction $\vec{l}_1$ that lies on plane $p$, passes through point $\vec{q}_1$ and maximises the following triple product:

$\left(\vec{q}_1 - \vec{q}_2 \right)\cdot \left(\vec{l}_1 \times \vec{l}_2\right)$

So something like this:

$\max\limits_{\vec{l}_1} \left(\vec{q}_1 - \vec{q}_2 \right)\cdot \left(\vec{l}_1 \times \vec{l}_2\right)$ w.r.t. $\vec{l}_1\cdot \vec{n} = 0$

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the triple product as $\vec l_1\cdot\left(\vec l_2\times\left(\vec q_1-\vec q_2\right)\right)=:\vec l_1\cdot\vec u$ to see that $\frac{\vec u}{\left|\vec u\right|}$ would maximise it absent the constraint. Then you just have to project out the normal vector:

$$
\frac{\vec u-\vec n\left(\vec n\cdot\vec u\right)}{\left|\vec u-\vec n\left(\vec n\cdot\vec u\right)\right|}\;.
$$